# Работа со строками в python

Tags: python, строки

Здравствуйте!
помогите мне с моей проблемой есть скрипт который обрашяется к бд mysql и с помошью запроса вытаскивает из бд следующие данные имеющие следующий вид: Dlink DES-3028 orb.001.prolet.151.sa1 10.0.0.78, эта целая строка, мне необходимо в выврде результата работы скрипта выводить только вот эту часть строки orb.001.prolet.151.sa1, подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать, ибо я новичек в питоне.

Comment: А Вы словами не смогли бы описать, какая часть результата запроса Вам нужна? Т.е. это всегда третье слово (разделение пробелами), последнее слово или ещё что нибудь. Или надо отбрасывать везде "Dlink DES-3028 "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю строка состоит из "оборудование" "Домен" "IP", если так то мы можем сделать так

```
s = "Dlink DES-3028 orb.001.prolet.151.sa1 10.0.0.78"
print s.split(' ')[-2]
```